# How do I choose a table based on an insert using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I don't understand how to make a choice in MySQL -- I think it is function....or maybe it is in the trigger?

When a new Document is entered into 'Document' table, I would the unique id created in Document.document_unique_id, transferred to one of 3 tables based on the value of Document.document_type.

table01: Document
--document_unique_id NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
--document_type
--date
--document_owner

table02:Document_Type
--letter
--email
--bill

table03:Document_letter
--letter_contents
--document.unique_id 
--document_letter_unique_id

table04:Document_Email
--email_contents
--document.unique_id
--document_email_unique_id

table05:Document_bill
--bill_contents
--document.unique_id
--document_bill_unique_id

what would the process be - sudo code will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a trigger
in trigger

```
if new.document_unique_id = 1 then
 insert into table02
elseif new.document_unique_id = 2 then
 insert into table03
elseif new.document_unique_id = 3 then
 insert into table04
end if
```